# Adding none value to entity in symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

In a Symfony form I have one field called `slot` that matches an entity with a custom query. let's say something like this:

```
->add('slot', 'entity', array(
    'label'             => 'Slot',
    'class'             => 'FooBarBundle:Slot',
    'property'          => 'name',
    'required'          => false,
    'query_builder'     => function(\Foo\BarBundle\Entity\SlotRepository $er) use ($ids) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.id IN(:ids)')->setParameter('ids', $ids);
    }
))
```

so far every thing works. The `slot` is a `ManyToOne` matching on the `Team` entity (for which the form is), so there can only be one slot selected at a time. As I said, every thing going according to plan. The user can select a slot and save it and every one's happy.

The trouble starts when you try to "unselect" a slot (yep that has to be possible). So I need to add a `none` value with a caption like `None of the listed items` or what ever. The question is how can I do that?

Comment: Maybe `'empty_data'  => null`, `'empty_value' => null` ?

Comment: As @absalon.valdes says, `'empty_value' => 'None of the listed items'` would do the job.

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I was looking for. I'll check it as soon as I get home. Could you might make an answer out of your comment, so I can accept it, once I tested it?

Comment: @absalon.valdes could you make an answer out of your comment? that was exactly, what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `empty_data` and `empty_value`:

```
->add('slot', 'entity', array(
    'label'             => 'Slot',
    'class'             => 'FooBarBundle:Slot',
    'property'          => 'name',
    'required'          => false,
    'query_builder'     => function(\Foo\BarBundle\Entity\SlotRepository $er) use ($ids) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.id IN(:ids)')->setParameter('ids', $ids);
    },

    'empty_data'  => null,
    'empty_value' => 'None of the listed items' /* or null */
))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that choice fields (which the `entity` field extends) are rendered within Symfony forms is defined by a certain kind of logic ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons)). I'm guessing that you're rendering a `<select>` dropdown, in which case if you're using Symfony 2.6 or above, `placeholder` is what you want ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder)). Be warned though, with certain databases (e.g. Postgres), the `placeholder` option was broken in Symfony 2.7.0 and (I think) 2.7.1.

The `empty_data` / `empty_value` issue with forms is part of a longstanding confusion. In short, use `placeholder`.